# Writing Shell script to launch app on ios device from xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, shell, ios5

Is it possible to launch an app on ios device using shell scripting as we do it on ios simulator?

Comment: Answer is NO. It is not possible

Comment: Answer is YES : it is possible with instruments. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at fruitstrap : https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap

Edit : 
since Xcode 5 (and Xcode Server) you can tell to xcodebuild which device you want to launch app on :
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html

```
xcodebuild -destination "name=KenjiPhone5" -scheme AppName test
```

The "install" action doesn't install/update app on the device, but the test one does it.

Comment: This (no longer maintained) tool installs the app on the device via Script, but it does not seem to be able to launch it.

Comment: I saw that `make debug` start a gdb session, maybe you can hack it to only launch the app and then leave gdb without killing the app...

Comment: Unstable and related to installing app into ios device.

Comment: @walle84 : sure, but I use it to deploy app on iOS 5/6 devices before running UIAutomation tests. I've edited my response to use the "official" way with instruments tool provided by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to load app via script in device.

I think there is no such facility provided by Apple. And if you want to submit the app on app-store then you need to follow all the set of rules provided by Apple.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there any tool similar to iphonesim that might be used?

Comment: I don't you can find a tool for non jail broken devices. http://code.google.com/p/mobilefinder/ might be helpful for jailbroken devices